# Kotlin Null safety issue for Nullable return from Java method in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, static-analysis, kotlin-null-safety

I have `Handler` which will process `Message` in Background Thread. When creating `Handler`, i have to pass `Looper` in constructor and its not `Nullable`. To get the `Looper` from background Thread i have to call `Looper.myLooper()` api and its return type is `Nullable`. So here issue arise as return type is `Nullable` i have to forcefully use `Not-Null Assertion (!!)` Operator.

This will create some static analysis issue in my project.Is there any way i can get rid from `!!` operator.

I want to know how others handle this issue.

Here is my sample code

```
private lateinit var myHandler : MyHandler 
............................................

val executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
executor.execute {
    Looper.prepare()
    myHandler = MyHandler(Looper.myLooper()!!)
    Looper.loop()
}

private inner class MyHandler(looper: Looper) : Handler(looper) {
    override fun handleMessage(msg: Message) {
        super.handleMessage(msg)
        //..................
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really wouldn't be using a SingleThreadExecutor with a looper like that.  Just use a Thread, or better yet a HandlerThread.  You gain no benefit from making it an executor here.  You also won't have this problem because the setup is done for you in HandlerThread.  And using a Looper would interfere with the scheduling logic of the Executor, because its never returning to the executor-  its stopping in the looper.

Ignoring that-  the answer here is to turn off the static analysis for this function.  Sometimes they bring up false positives.  That's why annotations like @SuppressWarnings exist, to tell tools that a particular usage is ok.  You're in a situation where you know that a null can't actually happen, but the compiler doesn't have that knowledge of the functions.  This is exactly where those annotations are meant to be used.

The other thing you can do is just put an if statement and throw an exception if it ever returns null.  But I find that not only pointless, but less clear-  you're adding extra code to check for a condition you know can't occur.  I'd rather have the suppress annotation with possibly a comment on it as to why.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. First time i have used `HandlerThread` , then i faced problem in unit test. I wasn't able to mock `HandlerThread`. Then i switched to `SingleThreadExecutor` . Thanks again.

Comment: "And using a Looper would interfere with the scheduling logic of the Executor, because its never returning to the executor- its stopping in the looper." -- Can you please explain a bit. or give me some resource to understand . Thanks

Comment: Executors are not meant to just do one task once.  They do many tasks serially.  But with setting up a looper, the first task will never finish.  This will prevent anything else ever being able to run on the ExecutorService.  If you want to run something forever, use a Thread.  ExecutorServices are meant to have requests end.  Since you're using Kotlin, I'd even argue for replacing it with a corutine.  If you're sending messages to a looper, a coroutin on the main thread is probably good enough, unless you're going to be actively calculating (and not waiting for IO) for hundreds of miliseconds

Comment: My usage case is sending `Message` to `Handler` with a delay. I used background thread  so that main thread can work freely. That `Handler` should live with application life cycle

Comment: @AbuYousuf Yeah, sounds like you could get rid of the Handler and just use the ExecutorService.  Really an ExecutorService is a replacement for threads with a Handler.  You wouldn't mix the two.